# Get a specific value in JSON and Python

Tags: python, json

I'm getting a JSON data from RESTCONF HTTPS request, using the following code.

```
https_request = 'https://' + host + '/restconf/data/Cisco-IOS-XE-native:native/interface/'
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/yang-data+json', 'Accept': 'application/yang-data+json'}
r = requests.get(https_request, auth=(user, password), headers=headers, verify=False)
print r.json()
```

The JSON file I got:

```
{
"Cisco-IOS-XE-native:interface": {
    "GigabitEthernet": [
        {
            "name": "1",
            "description": "DON'T TOUCH ME",
            "isis": {
                "Cisco-IOS-XE-isis:metric": {
                    "value": 2
             }
            ....
        },
        {
            "name": "2",
            "isis": {
                "Cisco-IOS-XE-isis:metric": {
                    "value": 4
                } ....

        },
        {
            "name": "3",
            "shutdown": [
                null
            ],
            "isis": {
                "Cisco-IOS-XE-isis:metric": {
                    "value": 7
                }....                
        }
    ],
    "Loopback": [
        {
            "name": 0,
            "isis": {
                "Cisco-IOS-XE-isis:metric": {
                    "value": 1
                }               
    ],
    "Tunnel": [
        {
            "name": 0,
            "isis": {
                "Cisco-IOS-XE-isis:metric": {
                    "value": 3
                }....
            }
    ]
}
```

Basically, I want my function to return the field's `"value"` of `isis` of each interface. I tried the following code for `GigabitEthernet`:

```
value = r.json()['Cisco-IOS-XE-native:interface']['GigabitEthernet'][0]['isis']['metric']['value']
```

I got this error:

```
print Router_1.get_isis_metric()['Cisco-IOS-XE-native:interface']['GigabitEthernet'][0]['isis']['metric']['isis']
KeyError: 'metric'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think, you have misspelled `metric` for `Cisco-IOS-XE-isis:metric`

Try :

```
value = r.json()['Cisco-IOS-XE-native:interface']['GigabitEthernet'][0]['isis']['Cisco-IOS-XE-isis:metric']['value']
```

**Edit 1**

```
for index in range(len(r.json()['Cisco-IOS-XE-native:interface']['GigabitEthernet'])):
    value = r.json()['Cisco-IOS-XE-native:interface']['GigabitEthernet'][index]['isis']['Cisco-IOS-XE-isis:metric']['value']
    print(value)
```

Comment: I think you've slightly mixed up the order of selectors. It should be `...['isis']['Cisco-IOS-XE-isis:metric']...` but you have them the other way round

Comment: OP wants the value of `isis` for each interface. You only solved the `KeyError` exception

Comment: @DanScally : You are correct.. modified.. thanks. .:)

Comment: @Eraw : I have added that too in Edit section.. Please check

Answer (score 3):

Using a list comprehension, where you iterate over the list of dictionaries and collect the value for each interface, example for `GigabitEthernet`

```
dct = {
"Cisco-IOS-XE-native:interface": {
    "GigabitEthernet": [
        {
            "name": "1",
            "description": "DON'T TOUCH ME",
            "isis": {
                "Cisco-IOS-XE-isis:metric": {
                    "value": 2
             }}

        },
        {
            "name": "2",
            "isis": {
                "Cisco-IOS-XE-isis:metric": {
                    "value": 4
                }}

        },
        {
            "name": "3",
            "shutdown": [
                None
            ],
            "isis": {
                "Cisco-IOS-XE-isis:metric": {
                    "value": 7
                }}
        }
    ]}}

result = [item['isis']["Cisco-IOS-XE-isis:metric"]['value'] for item in dct['Cisco-IOS-XE-native:interface']['GigabitEthernet']]
```

The output will be

```
[2, 4, 7]
```

Or to collect values for all interfaces, you can loop over the interfaces and collect the value for each interface

```
interfaces = ['GigabitEthernet', 'Loopback', 'Tunnel']
result = [item['isis']["Cisco-IOS-XE-isis:metric"]['value'] for interface in interfaces for item in dct['Cisco-IOS-XE-native:interface'][interface]]
print(result)
```

The output will be

```
[2, 4, 7, 1, 3]
```